# Mule changing the date format

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am trying to convert date from "dd-MM-yyyy" format to "dd/MM/yyyy"

```
 dob as Date {format: \"dd-MM-yyyy\"} as String {format :\"dd\/MM\/yyyy\"}
```

I am getting a dataweave parsing  error. Please help

Comment: Can you please paste an input example expected output. And the error you are getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dob as Date {format: "dd-MM-yyyy"} as String {format :"dd/MM/yyyy"}